# What mean this momentum-derivative?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, vectors, differentiation

I'm working with quantum gravity. I have to make a Taylor-series. I got some help for this, but I have problem with understanding the formalism. So, I have the operator $A((P-p)^2)$, which needs to expand in Taylor-series near $p$. The help that I got was to use operator $\partial_{p_{\mu}}$. Why? What does that mean? What is the difference beetween $p$ and  $p_\mu$?. $p_\mu = (p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3)$ is that equation right ? So, $p_{\mu}$ is a (coordinate?) representation for $p$?

And why is that true:

$\partial_{p_{\mu}} (P-p)^2 = 2 (P_{\mu}- p_{\mu})$

Comment: $P$ and $p$ are both four-vectors, and $p_\mu$ is the $\mu$th component of that four-vector. Here's a hint: $(P-p)^2=(P_\mu-p_\mu)(P^\mu-p^\mu)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function of $p^2 = p_\mu p^\mu$ has a [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) near $q$ of

$$f(p^2) = f(q) + \frac{\partial f(p^2)}{\partial p^\mu}\bigg|_{p = q}(p_\mu - q_\mu) + \frac{1}{2!}\frac{\partial^2 f(p^2)}{\partial p^\mu\partial p^\nu}\bigg|_{p = q}(p_\mu - q_\mu)(p_\nu - q_\nu) + \cdots$$

With this and the hint given to you by @probably_someone you should be able to work this out.